# wrap text values in string when using a mysql where in statement

Tags: php, mysql, implode, data-manipulation

I have an array of values that I implode to give me a comma separated list for use in a mysql where in clause.

```
SELECT count(id) FROM products WHERE id in (val1, val2, 3, 4, 5);
```

this statement breaks when the text value is not wrapped in quotes.

So theoretically I need to loop through the list first and wrap all text values before passing to the mysql statement.
Any Ideas?

**Code sample:**

```
$skus = array();

foreach($csv_array as $row)
{
        $skus[] = $row['skunumber'];                            
}

$skulist = implode(",",$skus);
```

**I fixed it with:**

```
foreach ($csv_array as $row)
{
    if (is_numeric($row['skunumber']))
    {
        $skus[] = $row['skunumber'];
    }
    else
    {
        $skus[] = '"'.$row['skunumber'].'"';
    }
}

$skulist = implode(",",$skus);
```

Comment: We have lot's of great ideas! Let's start with the one where you show us some code...the code that generates your list.

Answer (score 0):

Some quick suggest:

```
$arr = array('var', 3, 'var2', '5');

$inStr = "('".implode("', '", $arr)."')";
```

gives:

```
('var', '3', 'var2', '5')
```

Finally:

```
SELECT count(id) FROM products WHERE id in $inStr;
```